# Why do the two methylene protons in ethylbenzene have a chemical shift at 2-2.9?

Tags: spectroscopy, aromatic-compounds, nmr-spectroscopy, protons

The data sheet does not have any chemical shifts in this range for compounds containing only carbon and hydrogen

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE. Have a look at the 
[tour](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) to get familiar with this site. 
If necessary, mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here) 
using $\LaTeX$. Please note that there is a [homework policy](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange) here.

Answer (score 4):

Protons attached to a carbon that is connected to a benzene ring typically resonate in the range 2.2-2.9 ppm (see the Ar-C**H** range in [this table](http://www.cem.msu.edu/~reusch/OrgPage/nmr.htm)).

Here is the proton nmr spectrum for ethylbenzene.  The methylene protons absorb around 2.7 ppm, right in the upper end of the expected range.

[image]

[image source](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Organic_Chemistry/Spectroscopy)

Comment: Ok I believed Ar was for argon not Aromatic

Comment: Organic chemists use a number of abbreviations that look like element symbols. For example, $\ce{Ar}$ is aryl and $\ce{Ac}$ is acetyl, even though those symbols also stand for argon and actinium. We feel like we can get away with this because there are currently no known compounds with carbon-argon and carbon-actinium bonds.